# What is better opensource alternative for identifying small face other than yolo?

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, model-selection

I was trying to identify small face meaning that I want to know who that face belong to according to training dataset. I have previously use yolov4 to detect small object before and I know the accuracy is not very satisfying and I have read in internet that yolo is very terrible at detecting faces. Do anyone know what is the alternative opensource that is better than yolo v4 for identifying small face? Please share your knowledge. Thanks.

**Edit 1:** I mean like for identifying this face is for example angelina jolie face,etc(face recognition/ identification) not face detection(knowing existence of face)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [model](https://github.com/peiyunh/tiny) tailored for your problem. And here is the [research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04402.pdf) for the model.

Comment: Hi @Abhisek Verma thanks for answering but what i am seeking is face recognition not just face detection. Thanks

Comment: This is the first step. You have to do super resolution  then create a siamese like network or train normal CNN with Arface loss. This solves your first roadblock. The detection part.

Comment: yes that is actually true for extracting the face, but after that it means we need to train the faces with yolo, CNN, etc this is what I am trying to avoid because Yolo and CNN seems to be terrible at recognizing face according to the lots article that I read.

Comment: I told you what kind of network you need to use. Siamese network or standard CNN backbones like ResNet, Effnet etc. followed by ArcFace loss or other losses like these. And how would you propose to solve this problem if not using CNNs. CNNs work for images, just use them.